# How to setup mail relay at CentOs?

Tags: centos

I a totally newbie handling related to server. Now, my superior wants me to setup mail relay at centOs that will relay the mail to Y server. 
Centos does not have connection with our smtp server but Y server have.

the question is how to set up this mail relay?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Install Postfix

**Configuring the Relay Server**

Configure the /etc/postfix/main.cf file to use the external SMTP server.

Update the relayhost parameter to show your external SMTP relay host.

Important: If you specified a non-default TCP port in the sasl_passwd file, then you must use the same port when configuring the relayhost parameter.

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf
    # specify SMTP relay host 
    relayhost = [mail.isp.example]:587


At the end of the file, add the following parameters to enable authentication:

/etc/postfix/main.cf




    # enable SASL authentication 
    smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    # disallow methods that allow anonymous authentication. 
    smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
    # where to find sasl_passwd
    smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
    # Enable STARTTLS encryption 
    smtp_use_tls = yes
    # where to find CA certificates
    smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Save your changes.

Restart Postfix:

service postfix restart
```

Comment: Can I set up Y (solaris)  to appear as an "SMTP server" that just relays the emails/requests sent to it from Centos, to my actual SMTP server by using postfix?

Comment: if it is a standard SMTP server , yes you can

Comment: the relayhost = [mail.isp.example]:587 will be the solaris server?

Comment: yes, look at the port you will b using to relay

Comment: im sorry, im totally new here.. can you explain " look at the port you will b using to relay " ?

Comment: Default Ports:
Server:                          Authentication                                      Port:
Non-Encrypted         AUTH                                         25 (or 587)
Secure (TLS)                StartTLS                                         587
Secure (SSL)                SSL                                                  465

Comment: thanks.. if im use the ip adrres of y server  instead mail.isp.example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a recent version of Centos (6 or 7), You'll need to modify the postfix configuration.  At the end of /etc/postfix/main.cf, add the following line:

`relayhost = [y_server.domain.com]`

restart postfix:

`service postfix restart`

Comment: can i use ip adrees instead for [y_server.domain.com]?

Comment: Yes. Look at the docs for relayhost: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html